# Yocto - Install newer version of Valgrind

Tags: valgrind, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to install a newer version of Valgrind to my Yocto based system. The current version in the OE-Layer is 3.15, I want to install version [3.18](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta/recipes-devtools/valgrind/).
First of all, the question of whether my approach is correct (I have little experience with Yocto):

- I added the valgrind folder from the link above to my distro layer.
- Does bitbake automatically choose the newer version or do I have to configure it somewhere?

When i run bitbake, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: ParseError at <poky-path>../meta-blabla-distro/recipes-devtools/valgrind/valgrind_3.18.1.bb:53: unparsed line: 'do_patch:append() {'
```

How can this be? I have not changed the file and I can't find any error in the given line.

**Edit:**
After replacing all ":" by "_" in the bb file it is parsed successfully. But now I get this error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'glibc-src' (but <poky-path>/../meta-blabla-distro/recipes-devtools/valgrind/valgrind_3.18.1.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'glibc-src' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['glibc-src']
NOTE: Runtime target 'valgrind' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['valgrind', 'glibc-src']
ERROR: Required build target 'blabla-image-dev' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['blabla-image-dev', 'valgrind', 'glibc-src']
```

**Edit 2:**

I was able to build with Valgrind 3.17.

Comment: The approach is probably a sensible start if upgrading the whole system to the newer Yocto version is not an option... but upgrading single recipes is never guaranteed to work as is: In this case the recipe uses features that the bitbake in your Yocto version does not support. the error you see is likely the result of [this change](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/meta/recipes-devtools/valgrind?id=42344347be29f0997cc2f7636d9603b1fe1875ae) which you probably have to revert to make the recipe useful with your older bitbake.

Comment: IDK why `do_patch_append()` is written as `do_patch:append()`. Maybe the valgrind bb file is for newer version of Yocto. I remember, in order to extend any instructions such as install, it is required to add a `do_install_append()` instead of `do_install:append()`

Comment: Can anyone help me with the problem after the "Edit"? Is glibc-src another recipe I have to add?

Comment: I think yes, you need to add `meta` layer as well. It is simply `meta`. Run `bitbake-layers show-layers` to display all layers that are currently added, if it doesn't list the `meta` layer then you can add it using `bitbake-layers add-layer ../path/to/meta`. 
AFAIK, `meta` layer contains `glibc` source inside `recipes-core`